# What are good ways to learn how to make better looking iPhone applications?

Tags: ios, user-interface

So I have built an iPhone application using built in SDK controls, just wondering how I could make better looking applications like the ones displayed on http://pttrns.com/

Directions to books or tutorials would be grateful as well as any tips.

Comment: It's not just artwork that determines how something looks. Have a look at [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gestalt_psychology#Pr.C3.A4gnanz) which explains the importance of grouping in Gestalt Psychology

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Scoutzie](http://www.scoutzie.com/). It's a website for finding mobile designers and design ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Learn the art of graphics design, build your image assets, and stich them onto your views. You can do this a plethora of ways, not the least of which is custom drawing, image views, pattern colours... Alternatively, you can hire a designer like most of us do. :)

Point is, good iPhone interfaces are usually skinned by designers, or developers with design experience.

Answer (score 0):

Look at good apps and try to recreate the experience. When the UI Layout etc is good, there really is not much left thanlearn how to create sophisticated animations and learn photoshop!

In addition, apple has several guides in the UI topic. Look around in the dev center, there is much to discover!